# How to reformat dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I need to reformat dates. I'm currently having trouble with changing something in the format of `August 01, 2017` to `2017-08-01`, and I was wondering if someone could point to what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it.

This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(info[len(info)-1].text.strip(), '%m %d, %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

But I get an error:

> ValueError: time data 'July 31, 2019' does not match format '%m %d, %Y'

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: It doesn't work, I get an error ' ValueError: time data 'July 31, 2019' does not match format '%m %d, %Y'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong [format string](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).  `%m` is meant for numerical months, while `%B` is meant for the full localized name of the month.